# Photo album of the full-resolution photos shared through iCloud Photo Sharing?

Tags: icloud, photos, photo-stream

The photos that are shared through iCloud Photo Sharing shared albums are typically favorites, for example the best photos that you wanted to share with family over the course of several years. Over time these shared albums become valuable because they provide a filtered view of favorites from an otherwise huge and possibly unsorted photo library.

But the shared albums contain only lower-resolution photos unsuitable for prints and are limited to 5000 photos. To save the valuable photo selection and filtering work done for the shared albums for the future: Is it possible to, in any automated way, create albums in the Photos app with the full-resolution photos that have been shared through iCloud Photo Sharing?

An ideal solution could be for example to have a smart album showing all full-resolution photos from the photo library that have also been shared in iCloud Photo Sharing. This would also enable backing up albums with the original photos with Time Machine.